# How to take back a page to its previous state by clicking the back button of the browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a `link` to a `form`. After clicking the `link` the `form` shows up and the `link` disappears. The problem that i have is, when i click the browser's `back button`, the values of the URL is changed, but the state of the page doesn't go back to previous state. The `form` should disappear and the `link` shows back. Also on reload when the `form` is visible, the page goes back to its first state, which i need to prevent from happening.

Code :

```
<html>
<style>
  .titimmo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #CC3300;
    display: block;
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .visible {
    display: block;
  }

  #formContainer {
    padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    width: 88.9%;
  }

  #formContainer h4 {
    color: #FF3300;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div id="categContainer1">
  <div class="titimmo"><a href="add.php?c=realestate" id="a_categ">Real Estate</a></div>
</div>

<div id="formContainer" class="hidden">
  <form action="add.php" method="post">
    <h4>Location :</h4>
    <input type="text" name="made"/>
    <h4>Price :</h4>
    <input type="text" name="modele"/><br/><br/>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  function stepone() {
    document.getElementById('a_categ').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('categContainer1').className += " hidden";

      document.getElementById('formContainer').className = "visible";
      window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
      return false

    };
  }

  stepone();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- First question is: How to bring back the page to its previous state by clicking the browser's back button?
- Second question is: How to prevent the page from going back to its previous state - on reload when it's on second state (when form is visible)?

Comment: You would have to use session variables/cookies to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do to make it work:

1. To monitor browser back button click, use
   [window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)
   method
2. To remember the form state, you need to store the value in
   [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) or in a cookie.

This is a basic example:

```
var formVisible = localStorage.formVisible || false;
var cContainer = document.getElementById('categContainer1');
var fContainer = document.getElementById('formContainer');
function formOpen(e) {
    cContainer.className = "hidden";
    fContainer.className = "visible";
    window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
    localStorage.formVisible = 'Y';
    return false;
};
function formClose(e) {
    cContainer.className = "visible";
    fContainer.className = "hidden";
    localStorage.removeItem( 'formVisible' );
};
if( formVisible ) formOpen();
document.getElementById('a_categ').onclick = formOpen;
window.onpopstate = formClose;
```

```js
var formVisible = localStorage.formVisible || false;
var cContainer = document.getElementById('categContainer1');
var fContainer = document.getElementById('formContainer');
function formOpen(e) {
    cContainer.className = "hidden";
    fContainer.className = "visible";
    window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
 localStorage.formVisible = 'Y';
    return false;
};
function formClose(e) {
 cContainer.className = "visible";
    fContainer.className = "hidden";
 localStorage.removeItem( 'formVisible' );
};
if( formVisible ) formOpen();
document.getElementById('a_categ').onclick = formOpen;
window.onpopstate = formClose;
```

```css
.titimmo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #CC3300;
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}

#formContainer {
    padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    width: 88.9%;
}

#formContainer h4 {
    color: #FF3300;
}
```

```html
<div id="categContainer1">
    <div class="titimmo">
        <a href="add.php?c=realestate" id="a_categ">Real Estate</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="formContainer" class="hidden">
    <form action="add.php" method="post">
        <h4>Location :</h4>
        <input type="text" name="made" />
        <h4>Price :</h4>
        <input type="text" name="modele" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twuycjyf/1/), where **you can actually see how it works**.

Comment: Thank You very much @skobaljic, i really appreciate it. i tested it, it works well, except one small thing, when you hit `back button` and click the `link` again, the link doesn't disappear, it stays visible with the form, also if i paste the link directly to the browser, it shows the `form`, not the `link` (not first state) can you help me fix that ? again, thank you very much!

Comment: Think there was a typo saying `+= " hidden"`, should be `= "hidden"` - I've corrected it in snippet above. If you want to paste the code and event to be already defined to button, than using jQuery you would bind this way: `$('body').on('click', '#a_categ', formOpen)` (in pure Javascript would be harder, but not impossible).

Comment: Thank You very much @skobaljic, you are very kind, i'm doing this to learn some javascript, sadly i haven't learned jQuery yet, my knowledge is stil very basic, i don't know how to thank you!

Comment: i'm still having that issue when pasting the URL directly, it shows the `form` not the `link` as it should be, only if i clear browser's history then it goes to its first state, is that because of cookies or session not clearing?

Comment: We put the form state in browser's local storage. If you want to unset the item, than open the console and run `localStorage.removeItem( 'formVisible' );`

Comment: If i run `localStorage.removeItem( 'formVisible' );` from the console, it removes the item from local storage and it goes back to its first state, but somehow inside the function it is not working, also pasting this link `add.php?c=realestate` should go directly to the form, it goes to the link. I saw something like this in a website in french, Step Wizard that starts with links, wanted to know how it was done!